# Method wont return correct unless wrapped in arrow function

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, express, middleware

In my Node/Express API in order to protect my routes I am passport.authenticate

```
app.get('/', passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false}), (req, res) => { //whatever })
```

I have additional middleware on these routes and it gets rather long and I did not want to have to require passport into all my router files so inside a seperate file I created another method on an existing auth object called protect

```
const auth = {
   protect() {}
}
```

This allows me to do this

```
app.get('/', auth.protect, (req, res) => { //whatever })
```

Initially I tried to return the `passport.authenticate` line

```
const auth = {
   protect() {
      return passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false})
   }
}
```

But this **doesnt work**

I then wrapped it inside of an arrow function

```
const auth = {
    protect() {
       () => passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false})
    }
}
```

Now when I call `auth.protect` on my routes it works just fine.

Additionally if I just export an arrow function

```
export const protect = () => {
   return passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false})
}
```

This also works when I call `protect` on my routes.

Why do I need to return an arrow function with the code I want to run, why doesnt the first example with the return not work when I call the function on my route?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first example seems to return the result of the function execution, the second one returns a function.

Answer (score 1):

Wktrf is on the money.  To elaborate: app.get() requires two arguments, a path and a call back function.
http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.get

```
const auth = {
   protect() {
      return passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false})
   }
}
```

The above returns the result of passport.auth.  However a function is required as an argument for app.get().

```
const auth = {
    protect() {
       () => passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false})
    }
}
```

Your second example returns a function: `() =>  passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false})`
Which app.get() can then work with.

Hope this helps.